# What's new version for gorm-expect library support gorm.io/gorm?

Tags: go-gorm

I'm using https://github.com/lucaspizzo/gorm-expect to mock struct *gorm.DB. But this library just support github.com/jinzhu/gorm without support https://gorm.io/

Is any exists gorm-expect new version support gorm.io?

I'm trying convert jinzhu/gorm to gorm.io but It's not suitable way.